# Including the Navigational Bar

Tags: php, html, css

I have looked all over and can't seem to find an answer. I have two pages 1: default.html and the other navisystem.html. I want to include the navisystem into the html. I have tried

```
<!--#include virtual="navsystem.html" -->
```

AND

```
<!--#include file="navsystem.html" -->
```

AND (**BTW I changed my default.html to default.php when trying these below.**)

```
<?php
require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "navisystem.html");
?>
```

I also tried this:

```
require($_SERVER'DOCUMENT_ROOT' . "navisystem.html");
```

AND also this...

```
require("navisystem.html");
```

**ERRORS Returned:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: DOCUMENT_ROOT in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139
>
> Warning: require(navisystem.html) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'navisystem.html' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139

I have read that you have to change the php ini file to correct this error but not sure to what.

I am on a Windows 2008 Server. I am learning and don't know PHP well enough but I do know Classic asp and I don't want to use that because it's old. How do others include a navigation page into a regular HTML page? Any suggestions or help thank you!!

Comment: Is your file named `navisystem.html` or `navsystem.html`?

Comment: try $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined variable: DOCUMENT_ROOT in
>   C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139

as it says, there is no variable `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`. I think you meant `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

> Warning: require(navisystem.html) [function.require]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php
>   on line 139

File can't be found. Is it not obvious?

---

Edit: this seems to work for Frank:

```
<?php require dirname(__FILE__).'/navsystem.html' ?>
```

Comment: I have a funny feeling maybe because I am using a virtual directory its not able to find the file. Is there a way around that for testing?

Comment: try to use `require dirname(__FILE__).'/script.php'`

Comment: I tried it but no cigar!! `<?php
    
 require dirname("navisystem.html").'/script.php'
    ?>`

Comment: no. try `require dirname(__FILE__).'/navisystem.html'` leave `__FILE__` as it is. I also believe you have `navisystem.html` file in your directory `C:\webprojects\sites` or whenever your main file is

Comment: THAT WAS IT... SWEET... This is the fix: `<?php
    require dirname(__FILE__).'/navsystem.html'
    ?>` Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

change `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

TRY

```
 $projectFolder ='myProjectFolder'; // update after your comment
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$projectFolder.'/navisystem.html');
```

#### [DOCUMENT_ROOT](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The document root directory under which the current script is
>   executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Comment: Here what I have now... `<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "navsystem.html");
    ?>` and this is the error it's giving me. Warning: require_once(C:\webprojects\sites\navisystem.html) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\webprojects\sites\navisystem.html' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\webprojects\sites\default.php on line 139

Comment: Is it possiable that becuase I am using a virtual directory maybe it might not be seeing the file? http://www.website.com/virtualdirectory.

Comment: Is this correct syntax? `<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/barker/navsystem.html"; ?>` If so this is the error: Warning: require_once(**C:\webprojects\sites/barker/navsystem.html**) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\webprojects\sites\barkerlawfirm\default.php on line 139 Notice the path doesn't look right?

Comment: Nope, I tried it `<?php
    $projectFolder ='barker'; // update after your comment
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$projectFolder.'/navisystem.html');
    ?>` and it returns the same error above.

Comment: It has to have something to do with the virtual directory. Because looking at the error the page is for ex: c:\websites\website1/website2/... and even when I try /website2/file its still messed up.

Comment: @FrankG.  your question is not clear. please re write your question.

Comment: Sorry, what I am trying saying is that using a virtual directory is showing the error url like this for example: c:\websites\yahoo/google/file.html. But to test the site you would go to `http://www.yahoo.com/google`. For some reason or another the tranisition from the virtual directory is failing even if I do `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/google/navsiystem.html";` I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I got the answer it was below. But I wanted to say Thank you very much for your efforts and help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Document_root is a GLOBAL value for SERVER variable.

thus,

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "navisystem.html");
?>
```

Comment: I have a funny feeling maybe because I am using a virtual directory its not able to find the file. Is there a way around that for testing?

Comment: well, in that case just browse through your files! The code mentioned above will work when there is a navisystem.html file present in the root directory of your virtual host. You need to find and locate the path of navisystem.html before you could `require` it.

Answer (score 0):

rename default.html to default.php and try

```
<?php
  require_once "navisystem.html";
?>
```